# Need help aligning tsparticles.js .SVG polygonmask to a <section data-background="image">

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, particles.js

I'm trying to align a SVG thats coming in from tsparticles to my background inside a section data-background tag/atrib.

```
            <section class="home-section bg-dark-alfa-30 parallax-2" data-background="images/full-width-images/TEST.svg" id="home">
                <div id="tsparticles"></div>
                    <script src="js/tsparticles.js"></script>
                    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

I'm very close but just can't figure out the exact way to do it.

(I'll deal with responsiveness later)

For now I would give an arm to understand what I'm doing wrong.

I created the image and SVG from exactly the same file, I've checked the resolution is the same, but the SVG refuses to align as I would expect it too.

```
            <section class="home-section bg-dark-alfa-30 parallax-2" data-background="images/full-width-images/TEST.svg" id="home">
                <div id="tsparticles"></div>
                    <script src="js/tsparticles.js"></script>
                    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
                <div class="js-height-full container">
                    
                    <!-- Hero Content -->
                    <div class="home-content">

                        <div class="home-text"> 
                            <h1 class="hs-line-12 font-alt mb-50 mb-xs-30">
                                <img src="images/title-logo2.png" alt="Company logo" />
                                <!--Chris <p style="color:#000000">Theobald</p>-->
                            </h1>
                            
                            <h2 class="hs-line-8 no-transp font-alt mb-50 mb-xs-30">
                                More than <p style="color:#000000">technology</p>
                            </h2>
                            
                            
                            
                            <div class="local-scroll">
                                <a href="#about" class="btn btn-mod btn-border-w btn-medium btn-round hidden-xs">See More</a>
                                <!-- <span class="hidden-xs">&nbsp;</span>-->
                                
                            </div>                                  
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Hero Content -->
                    
                    <!-- Scroll Down -->
                    <div class="local-scroll">
                        <a href="#about" class="scroll-down"><i class="fa fa-angle-down scroll-down-icon"></i><span class="sr-only">Scroll to the next section</span></a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Scroll Down -->
                    </div>
            </section>
            <!-- End Home Section -->
```

And CSS

```
/* ==============================
   Home sections
   ============================== */
  
/*
 * Header common styles
 */

.home-section {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;    
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: -2;
}

.home-content{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Home content */

.home-content{
    position: relative;
}
.home-text{
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#tsparticles{
  position: static;
}
```

This is at 1920 x 1080
It doesn't scale with screen size yet, I'm just looking for a sure fire way to align the background image sitting in the section tag with the svg coming in from tsparticles app.js
[image]

This link kinda looks like its the problem?
you can see its off center in the preview here...
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by removing the data-background image from the section tag and using

```
#tsparticles {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url("https://christheobald.com/images/full-width-images/TEST.svg"); --> this fixed it here.
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

in the CSS